# eclipse não reconhece jdk 9, 11 ou 14 (Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.) windows 10

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jdk

Estou tentando testar o JDK9 com Eclipse (versão 2020-09 M3 (4.17.0 M3) e também testei com a Oxygen Release (4.7.0)) no Windows 10.

Instalei a jdk com o instalador para windows *jdk-11.0.8_windows-x64_bin.exe* e também instalei a JRE.
**O java 1.8 continua funcionando normalmente.**

Ao inserir o JDK o eclipse (Window > Preferences > Installed JREs > add > Standard VM > Directory...) me retorna essa mensagem *Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found* e eu não consigo clicar em *finish*

[image: screen shot da tela de adicionar jvm com erro no eclipse]

Coisas que já tentei:

- mudar variável de ambiente do windows para a JDK 9
- testar com outras versões de JDK 11 e 14
- testar em outras versões de Eclipse
- testar em outro computador
- instalar em outro disco
- usar o zip ao invés do instalador

Alguém teve esse problema? Sabe como resolver?

Comment: você poderia editar a pergunta e incluir a mensagem de erro?

Comment: sim, mas o erro é o do título Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found

Comment: ja tentou este link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029647/target-is-not-a-jdk-root-system-library-was-not-found-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-jav

Comment: @CodigodeSenior funciona parcialmente. Na versão mais antiga do eclipse não funcionou, continua com o mesmo problema. Acho que a principal dúvida é pq funciona essa JDK e na da oracle não funciona?

Comment: não sei muito sobre o Eclipse, o máximo que consegui encontrar foi esse, caso eu encontre outro mais util aviso

Comment: Experimente em vez de colocar a pasta `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8` colocar a pasta `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\jre`. Apesar do erro sugerir que deve ser colocada a pasta-raiz da JDK, talvez o que ele queira seja a pasta-raiz da JRE, como sugere o nome do campo "JRE home". Se não der certo tente também, caso houver, a pasta C:\Program Files\Java\jre-alguma-coisa, que pode ser instalada à parte (a JDK vem com a JRE, mas você também pode instalar ela separada).

Comment: verifique se a versão do eclipse e do jdk são x32 ou x64. Pelo caminho que você mostrou, o jdk é x64, então verifique se o eclipse também é.

Comment: eclipse e jdk x64!!!

Answer (score -2):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema tentando instalar o Java17. Ele foi descompactato no diretório jdk-17.0.8 e não reconhecia. Eu renomeei o diretíorio para "jdk-17.0" e funcionou. No seu caso basta alterar para "jdk-11.0"